# How do I start afresh with git?

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repository.  I did not edit the repository, but git pull -rebase is telling me I need to commit changes first.  I just want to overwrite and start with the current repository.  I thought a pull would do that, but for some reason git thinks I edited the repo.  Help!

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more clearly? It's a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
git fetch origin # get all branches from remote repo
git reset --hard origin/master # discard whatever you have and switch to master branch of remote repo
```

Comment: Will the command change the files in the working directory? Need to reassure

Comment: Fornutately i took a backup before i tried your commands :) Yess the comands fetch and reset wiped replaced everything

Answer (score 1):

Most simple solution would be to remove it and start over by cloning it again, you probably changed something by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `git checkout -f` to force a recheckout/revert of all files within the branch you're currently working in. Obviously, this will nuke all changes without much recourse.